# Is every continuous function $f$ on $\mathbb{R}$ locally integrable?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I know that in general, constants, continuous functions and integrable functions are locally integrable.  However, I would like to construct a proof for a particular case that;

Every continuous function $f$ on  $\mathbb{R}$ is locally integrable, that is, $f\in L^1_{\text{loc}}.$

Comment: Yes. On a compact set, a continuous function is bounded and on a compact set $L^\infty \subset L^1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  A function $f$ is *locally integrable* on $\mathbb{R}$ if
$$ \int_K |f| < \infty $$
for all compact subsets $K \subseteq \mathbb{R}$.

Now, to prove the result, suppose that $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$, and that $K\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is compact.  We now make two observations:

1. On a compact set, a continuous function is bounded. Therefore there is some real number $M > 0$ such that $|f(x)| < M$ for all $x\in K$, and
2. By the Heine-Borel Theorem, every compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is bounded.  From this, it follows that $\mu(K) < \infty$, where $\mu$ is the usual Lebesgue measure.

Integrating, we obtain
$$ \int_{K} |f|
\le \int_{K} M
= M \mu(K).$$
Since both $M$ and $\mu(K)$ are finite, their product is also finite, which gives the desired result.